# Can i check whether access_token is issued or not in e2e Testing? (Protractor)

Tags: angular, authentication, protractor, access-token, e2e-testing

I am new to e2e testing using protractor. I want to ask that while hitting a URL directly, Can we check whether access_token is issued or not? Is there any built-in functions in protractor that can help us manipulating the access_token. I have tried using `executeScript` but it didn't work.

What I am doing is to test certain functionalities in a component and then before moving to next component i want to check whether the user has access_token or not. If user has access_token he should be allowed to next component otherwise he should be directed to the login page for login

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your user is authenticated, you will have the access token. There are two ways to do this:

1) You can manually login by passing the basic authentication.

2) You can send your authentication token through the url with the username:password@url format.

3) You can add a token in cookie and then add it to the browser using the `browser.manage.addCookie()` function. This is my favourite one. You can use this to add a cookie in your browser. This can be a basic auth token, session auth token etc. Unless you close your browser, the user will stay authenticated.

If you want to clear the local storage and cache, you can run the following command after each test runs.

```
afterEach(async (done) => {
        await browser.executeScript('window.localStorage.clear();');
        done();
});
```

To know more about cookies in protractor, read [this](https://chercher.tech/protractor/cookies-protractor#handling-cookies-with).

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks, A lot. the third one is the perfect solution. Thanks again.

Comment: is there any way in which there are sessions intead of cookies. How to check login when there are no cookies used

Comment: You will be saving the session information somewhere in the browser. Like local storage or cache. You should be able to find a command in protractor that extracts that value or checks the presence of that value. Question is, how are you creating that session login.

Comment: Its token based authentication.

Comment: I guess now i will need localStorage access ?